# Create a multi-dimensional array from a CSV logic

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array, fgetcsv

I wanna create an *array* that follow my "*CSV logic*" but I'm struggling.

Here is kind of an example of the content of the *CSV*:

```
+------------+----------+-------------+---------+
|    Name    | Duration |    User    |  Level   |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+
| Bestall    | 7 Days   |            |    T     |
| Bestleft   | 6 Days   |            |   ST     |
| Turn       | 2 Days   |   Brother  |          |
| Jump       | 4 Days   |   Sister   |          |
| Bestdown   | 1 Day    |            |   ST     |
| Play       | 1 Day    |   Sister   |          |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+
```

So, what I try to achieve is to create a dimension per ***Level***.

T stands for *Title* and ST for *SubTitles*.

With this example, the resulting array would be:

```
[Bestall] => Array 
         (
            [Duration] => 7 Days
            [Bestleft] => Array 
                       (
                         [Duration] => 6 Days
                         [0] => Array 
                             (    
                                [Name] => Turn     
                                [Duration] => 2 Days
                                [User] => Brother
                             )
                         [1] => Array 
                             (    
                                [Name] => Jump
                                [Duration] => 4 Days
                                [User] => Sister
                             )
                       )
            [Bestdown] => Array
                       (                           
                         [Duration] => 1 Day
                         [0] => Array 
                             (    
                                [Name] => Play
                                [Duration] => 1 Day
                                [User] => Sister
                             )
                       )
         )
```

My actual code for this (not working)

```
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $level = $row[count($row)-1];
            $titled = false;
            if($level=='T') {
                $titled = $row[0];
                $data[$titled] = $row;
            }
            elseif($level=='ST')
                $data[$titled][] = $row;
            array_push($data[$titled], $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
```

Comment: provide the code,what u had tried yet

Comment: Actually what I tried basically didn't work. I just know how to read the csv line per line, after that I'm stuck.

Comment: Whats your logic?

when first column value is "Bestall" you need all the other line to be child of it?

When the first col value is "Bestleft" you need other lines to be child of it till you get the next key word?

are "Bestall", "Bestleft" and "Bestdown" your logic key words?

Please explain the exact logic assuming that you are reading line by line. not the array that you expect!

Comment: You read csv on the basis of "Level". i didnt found in ur array. and what is the logic here

Comment: @masterFly the Bestxxx are just for the examples, in reality it's just project names so they differs. But you understood the way I want it. A Project with "T" Level will have the others lines child of him and same apply for "ST" Level but for lines until another "ST" Level

Comment: Do you have the code line to read the csv line right? I think you should have it. I will assume that You are in a loop, and each instance you get array of items in the row.

Comment: @masterFly Yeah you're right. I added my (not working) code in the post so you see. Anyway, know that I don't have any constraints for reading the CSV, so if you have a better way of doing iit along with my problem, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the php code you need:

```
$data = array();
$t = false;
$st = false;

if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
{
    $header = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter);

    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $level = $row[count($row)-1];

        if($level=='T') {
            $t = $row[0];
            $data[$t][$header[1]] = $row[1];
        }
        elseif($level=='ST'){

            $st = $row[0];

            $data[$t][$st][$header[1]] = $row[1];
        }
        else{

            $tmp_row = array(
                $header[0] => $row[0],
                $header[1] => $row[1],
                $header[2] => $row[2]
                );

            $data[$t][$st][] = $tmp_row;    
        }

    }
    fclose($handle);
}

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example CSV to create array

```
$filename = base_url() . 'yor_file.csv';

$content = file_get_contents($filename);

$lines = explode("\n", $content);

$lenthOfCsvRows = 50;
$tempArray = array();
$csvArray = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $lenthOfCsvRows; $i++) {
    $data = explode("\t", $lines[$i]);

    $tempArray['nameKey'] = array(
        '1' => $data[0],
        '2' => $data[1],
        '3' => $data[2],
        '4' => $data[3],
    );
    $csvArray[]= $tempArray;
}
print_r($csvArray);
```

Comment: Thanx, but that's pretty not what I asked for.